# Why couldn't this character in 'Better Call Saul' be a paralegal or take a similar role?

Tags: united-states, unlicensed-practice, new-mexico, law-in-fiction

In Season 3 of *Better Call Saul*,

> Jimmy McGill receives a one year suspension from the New Mexico Bar Association. During this time, he does various odd jobs but what he doesn't do is help his (romantic and law) partner, Kim Wexler, who is buried under a mountain of legal work.

Could this character have helped that person with the legal paperwork in the same capacity as a paralegal -- filing documents, proofreading, etc. could?  Or would the situation prevented them from doing this type of work?

Comment: I guess the question is: can a disbarred or sanctioned attorney work as a paralegal or other peri-legal occupation that doesn’t require entry into the bar.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Jimmy was suspended for forging legal documents that he had access too?  If so, I'm pretty sure handling legal documents while disbarred might have been part of the agreement, especially since Wexler benefited from his forgery and she wouldn't want another incident like that marring her fledgling law office a second time.  It would be akin to asking why we don't let a convicted Ax-murder chop the prison's firewood because he clearly knows his way around an ax.